# .hide() is not a function error when executing from a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to loop over a few different labels and hide their content based on if a radio button is check or not. This is the solution I came up with, but I keep getting an error in the console.

```
var hazardOptions = $(".js-hazardous-option");
var hazard = $("input[name=Hazardous]");
for (var i = 0, len = hazard.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (hazard[i].id === "HazardousYes" && hazard[i].checked) {
        for (var ii = 0, length = hazardOptions.length; ii < length; ii++) {
            hazardOptions[ii].show();
        }
    } else if (hazard[i].id === "HazardousNo" && hazard[i].checked) {
        for (var iii = 0, leng = hazardOptions.length; iii < leng; iii++) {
            hazardOptions[iii].hide();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> hide() is not a function

Not sure what I'm missing, I've tried having a look online for a similar issue, but with no luck. I'm pretty sure that the problem is here: `hazardOptions[iii].hide();` but not really sure why and/or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Without it, it is hard to know what is wrong.

Comment: IIRC accessing an array object via index gives you the DOM element and not the JQuery object. You effectively need to do `$(hazardOptions[iii]).hide();` to get it working

Comment: hide()/show() are JQuery functions. You are trying to apply them to Javascript variables.

Comment: Is there a single input with an id equal to either HazardousYes or HazardousNo? Or do you have multiples with those IDs?

Comment: Please check out my solution - I think it would greatly simplify your code and give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have a list of objects from a JQuery selector, if you try to access them via index you actually get the DOM element back and not the JQuery object. It's confusing for sure but [it is in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

What you effectively need to do is turn it back into a JQuery object:

```
$(hazardOptions[iii]).hide();
```

Or you can use the [`eq()` function](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) with *does* provide the JQuery object ad thus still has the `hide()` function:

```
hazardOptions.eq(iii).hide();
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery's built-in `.each()`? You're wrapping DOM elements, unwrapping, and re-wrapping. Just keep them wrapped and iterate over them

Comment: @mhodges: On second thought, the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) suggests it requires the same anyway...

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I was thinking `.each()` kept a wrapped copy of the DOM element. IMHO I hate how jQuery does their iterator functions lol. Either way, the code can be significantly simplified - see my solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to wrap it with `$`

```
$(hazardOptions[ii]).hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you currently have it, if `hazard.id === "HazardousYes"`, you are showing all hazardOptions, and if it is `"HazardousNo"`you are hiding all of them.

You can call `.show()` and `.hide()` on a jQuery collection and it will apply that to **all elements in the collection**. The below code will replicate the logic of your original code, however, the hazardOptions final show/hide state will be solely determined by the last hazard that is checked and has an id equal to "HazardousYes" and "HazardousNo". This may be what you want, but I would imagine it's not.

```js
var hazardOptions = $(".js-hazardous-option");
var hazards = $("input[name=Hazardous]");
hazards.each(function (index, hazard) {
  if (hazard.checked) {
    if (hazard.id === "HazardousYes") {
      hazardOptions.show();
    } else if (hazard.id === "HazardousNo") {
      hazardOptions.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit** - Come to think of it, if you don't have elements with duplicate IDs, You can make this really simple:

```
hazardOptions.show($("#HazardousYes").is(":checked")); 
hazardOptions.hide($("#HazardousNo").is(":checked"));
```